# Fail to upgrade MySQL from 8.0.3 to 8.0.14

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

I want to upgrade MySQL server from `8.0.3` to `8.0.14`. The following steps I have followed:

1. Start the a mysql container with version 8.0.3

   ```
   $ docker run --rm --name=tmp1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v $PWD/Desktop/mysql-debug/:/var/lib/mysql mysql:8.0.3
   ```
2. After running the container,

   ```
   $ docker exec -it tmp1 mysql -uroot -proot -e "select 1;"
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   +---+
   | 1 |
   +---+
   | 1 |
   +---+

   $ docker exec -it tmp1 mysql -uroot -proot -e "show databases;"
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   | mysql              |
   | performance_schema |
   | sys                |
   +--------------------+

   $ docker exec -it tmp1 mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database abc;"
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

   $ docker exec -it tmp1 mysql -uroot -proot -e "show databases;"
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | abc                |
   | information_schema |
   | mysql              |
   | performance_schema |
   | sys                |
   +--------------------+
   ```
3. Remove the previous one and run a new container with version 8.0.14 and also use the same data dir as for 8.0.3 (`$PWD/Desktop/mysql-debug/:/var/lib/mysql`)

   ```
   $ docker rm -f <mysql_container_id>
   $ docker run --rm --name=tmp1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v $PWD/Desktop/mysql-debug/:/var/lib/mysql mysql:8.0.14
   ```

But, I got the following error:

```
$ docker run --rm --name=tmp1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v $PWD/Desktop/mysql-debug/:/var/lib/mysql mysql:8.0.14
2020-01-21T07:38:53.346774Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-01-21T07:38:53.346846Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.14) starting as process 1
2020-01-21T07:38:55.793052Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013326] [Server] Upgrading the server from server version '0' is not supported.
2020-01-21T07:38:55.793067Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-01-21T07:38:55.793257Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-01-21T07:38:55.793504Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-01-21T07:38:56.513813Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.14)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

What I need to do to overcome this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from MySQL 8.0.3 to 8.0.14 is not supported. I have found more information about `MySQl` upgrading process from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html)